# Processing input in a function in Python 3.3

Tags: python, string, list, format, output

I have a question about formatting output. Pretty simple probably but I've been working on stuff for like 10 hours so I just can't figure out why it won't work

```
elif command.startswith("TOP") and len(command) > 3:
        digi_trans = str.maketrans('', '', string.digits)
        char_trans = str.maketrans('', '', string.ascii_letters)
        bracket_trans = str.maketrans('', '', "[']")
        subset = command.translate(digi_trans)[3:]
        if subset == "EDITORS":
            top_names = []
            count = 0
            count_limit = int(command.translate(char_trans))
            top_names = sorted(name_temp.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
            largest = heapq.nlargest(count_limit, top_names, key=operator.itemgetter(1, 1))
            print(largest)
```

This is the part of my code that's messing with me. The top_names list is just a sorted list of two item pairs, one name and one value.

It currently outputs this (assuming I wanted the top 2 values in my command):

```
[('Tzartzam', [16]), ('Quercusrobur', [14])]
```

I'd like for it to output something like this:

```
--------------------
Tzartzam        [16]
Quercusrobur    [14]
--------------------
```

The funny thing is, I already have a part of my program that does almost the exact same thing, but I just can't understand what I'm doing differently so I'd just appreciate it if someone would point me in the right direction :(

Comment: Only one line of that code is relevant to your question! Also: "I already have a part of my program that does almost the exact same thing" - so make it a function, and call it from both places.

Comment: I have tried but it always ends up giving me a list index out of range error for some reason. I'm sure I'm just overtired and it's flying right over my head for that reason because it seems really simple.

Comment: We can't tell you the difference between this code and the other part of your program, because you didn't post the other part. For all we know, it's doing `print nice_formatted(largest)`, and you forgot to call it this time.

Comment: The only place largest appears is here, it's just the name I assigned for the heapq function. I did what jonrsharpe suggested and turned that other piece of code into a function and it worked perfectly! I didn't even have to change much

Answer (score 0):

You can use rjust and ljust:

```
top_names=[('Tzartzam', [16]), ('Quercusrobur', [14])]
print "--------------------"
for n in top_names:
    print n[0].ljust(16),str(n[1][0]).rjust(3)
print "--------------------"
```

Output:

```
--------------------
Tzartzam          16
Quercusrobur      14
--------------------
```